# Getting blank page in angular cordova app

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I'm trying to run a HelloWorld application in Angular + Cordova, but it does not work well when I run it with the ios emulator (iPhone 12 Pro Max - iOS 14.4). I'm getting a blank page (screenshot below).

I have already changed the **href="/"** in my index.html to **href="./"** but it doesn't work. I added ios platform with "**cordova platform add ios**" command line and I have installed all the requirements as: XCode, ios-deploy and CocoaPods tools.

I created the Angular project with Angular CLI and did not modify anything. After, I created the Cordova project inside and linked the **dist** folder to the **www** folder.

Versions:
**Cordova** version 10.0.0 - **Angular** version 11.2.9 - **Angular CLI** version 11.2.8 - **Node** version 15.14.0

[Blank Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QhFs.png)

this is the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

this is the index.html file in **www folder**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HelloWorldAngularCordova</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.7b63b9fd40098a2e8207.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js" defer></script><script src="main.80cad638da592e13f2e3.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Where is my error(s)? Thanks

Comment: have same problem ... did you manage to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”cordova.js”></script>
```

in your index.html file.
Then in main.ts:

```
    let onDeviceReady = () => {
      platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    };document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

like here:
[binding angular with cordova](https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79)